# Sly.js - Horizontal Scroll issue on Chrome Win10

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, sly-scroller

I'm using sly.js for horizontal scrolling. It works fine on every browser except on Chrome for Win10. In particular, when I scroll the page and cursor is on an item of sly.js it scroll horizontally. What I want is to scroll horizontally only with drag/pan event.
The behavior is correct on Chrome for Ubuntu, Chrome for Mac OS, Safari, Firefox, Edge. An example is here http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html